# Can't find symbology layer for ESRI Global Land Cover

Tags: data, arcgis-online, land-cover

I have downloaded part of the ESRI Global Land Cover (https://livingatlas.arcgis.com/landcover/) as a raster but I am missing the symbology/legend info. The raster obviously contains numerical values only and I am looking for the mapping between the semantic classes and the numbers (e.g., 1: Water, 2: Shrub etc.). I have looked and googled everywhere I could think of but haven't found it. The closest thing I've found is https://gee-community-catalog.org/projects/esrilc2020/ but I am not sure where it comes from and if it's reliable.

For example, the website of a similar product from ESA (https://esa-worldcover.org/en/data-access) contains a section "Symbology" section where the .qml and .lyr files are available for download.

Where do I find ESRI Global Land Cover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class values are mentioned on the [official website](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=fc92d38533d440078f17678ebc20e8e2). A raster function template is also provided [here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b69d5c69960c491b839fa7e06c4d2d44). It will automatically apply the symbology with class names.

1 -- Water

2 -- Trees

4 -- Flooded vegetation

5 -- Crops

7 -- Built Area

8 -- Bare ground

9 --  Snow/Ice

10 -- Clouds

11 -- Rangeland